# What is the difference between j, CTRL-J, <NL> and CTRL-N in normal mode?

Tags: cursor-movement

I saw somewhere on the web someone using `Ctrl-J` and as I didn't know this mapping I looked up in [the relevant doc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#j) and found the following:

```
j           or
<Down>      or
CTRL-J      or
<NL>        or
CTRL-N          [count] lines downward linewise.
```

Which leads me to several questions:

- **What is `<NL>`**: I would see it as an equivalent of `<CR>` since pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will go down one line in normal mode by default but why is it `<NL>` here and not `<CR>`?
- **What is the difference between these mappings**: Do all of these 5 options go one line down in the same way? According to my tests I would answer yes but that would lead to my next question.
- **Why are there 5 mappings to do the exact same thing**: I can understand that `j` and `<down>` are kept for users who are not used to vim mappings, but why do the other mappings exist?
- **When is it more interesting to use one more than the other**: That is a continuation of the previous question: if there is so many possibilities I guess that they have different advantages or are better to use in specific use cases. What are those use cases?

I find the redundancy of these commands even more strange when I look at [`:h k`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#k): there are only 3 ways to go up: `k`, `<UP>` and `ctrl-p`. So the bonus question is: **Why are there 5 ways to go down and only 3 to go up?**

Comment: Are you sure they were using the default `Ctrl-J` binding?  It seems to be common, at least among those I know, to map `Ctrl-J/K` to "down/up until the next line with the same indentation level as the starting line".

Comment: I'd like to answer to " Why are there 5 ways to go down and only 3 to go up?" Well - it's because, in life, things *go south* way easier! :)

Comment: @VanLaser really great answer, they should consider adding this hint in the doc! ;-)

Comment: @VanLaser Too bad isn't it. At that rate all the humanity will descend into nothingness in no time!

Comment: "Abandon hope, all ye who `<CR>` here"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Interesting that you mentioned `<CR>`. `<CR>` or carriage return, technically used to mean *go to the start of the line*. `<NL>`, or newline aka line feed (usually called `LF`), was used to mean *go to the next line*. Over time, the distinction was lost in most applications.<sup>1</sup> Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> actually yields a carriage return, usually (try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> - you should see `^M` in Unix terminals). `<NL>`'s control code is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> surprised me. According to [`man ascii`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ascii.7)<sup>2</sup>, it is a *shift out* character:

```
Oct   Dec   Hex   Char                        Oct   Dec   Hex   Char
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
016   14    0E    SO  (shift out)             116   78    4E    N
```

The *shift in* and *shift out* characters, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_Out_and_Shift_In_characters):

> ... provided a way to shift, hence the nomenclature, a coloured ribbon, split longitudinally usually with red and black, up and down to the other  colour in an electro-mechanical typewriter or teleprinter ...

How it ended up meaning *go down* is a mystery to me.

---

> Why are there 5 ways to go down and only 3 to go up?

Well, the three ways to go up all have corresponding ways to go down. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> presumably is the complement of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>, implying that the *shift in/out* is not relevant here). The extra two ways down (`<NL>` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>) are actually two representations of the same way. `<NL>` is an inheritance from the typewriter days - and in those days, I don't think there was a key to go up - only to go down.

See also:

- [What are carriage return, linefeed, and form feed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3091524/2072269)

<sup><sup>1</sup> It still matters in some cases (printing `\r` (carriage return) and `\n` (line feed) using most formatted printing functions/tools still retain the old meaning.).</sup>

<sup><sup>2</sup> This table is arranged in such a manner that the alphabet corresponds to the control code of the character on the same line.</sup>

Comment: I always thought `Ctrl-N` was for _next_, and `Ctrl-P` was for _previous_. That's what they stand for in Emacs, anyway, in which they are bound to `next-line` and `previous-line`. Also, `Ctrl-P` is not _shift in_; it is [_data link escape_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#DLE). _Shift in_ is `Ctrl-O`.

Comment: @Lithis I stand corrected.

Comment: @Lithis Honestly, the only thing I know about Emacs is c-x c-e.

Comment: Historical and clear answer, thanks a lot Muru! I should have thought of the ascii code of the characters the answer often lies in there.

Comment: @muru That's too bad since Emacs actually has a lot to offer, especially its org-mode which has been massively helpful to me. I recommend you check out the project Spacemacs https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/ , which focuses heavily on Vim emulation so that you don't need to know any traditional Emacs command to use. Maybe that'll change your perception a bit.

Comment: @XiangJi no doubt, but I don't see any need to use it. Wherever I'm likely to find Emacs, I'm also likely to find Vim. On every system I administer, either vim-gnome or vim-nox (in terms of Ubuntu packages) is installed. Emacs is only installed where someone has requested it.

Answer (score 8):

See `:help key-notation`.

1. `<NL>` means "linefeed" and `<CR>` means "carriage return".

   Those are two different ways to break the current line. They are historically bound to different control characters (`ctrl-j` and `ctrl-m`) but are usually inserted with the same key, `<CR>`. I agree that using `<NL>` in this context seems counterintuitive.
2. All those "mappings" (they are not actually mappings) behave exactly the same way.
3. History, mostly, also cross-platform constraints.

   There were no dedicated motion keys Bill Joy's terminal but the arrows decals were on the `hjkl` keys. Since modal editors were rare at the time, pressing those keys only inserted the associated character in whatever you were doing. You had to press `<C-h>`, `<C-j>`, `<C-k>` and `<C-l>` to move the cursor on the screen.

   As you can see, there's quite an overlap between `j`, `<C-j>`, `<NL>` and `<Down>`. `<C-n>` generally meaning "next" in Vim, it's easy to see how it got lumped together with its comrades.
4. Since they are all synonymous, you are free to use the one that works best for you.

   `<CR>`, for example, is an interesting key to use for your own mappings.

Comment: Thanks for the enlighting! I greatly agree on the `<CR>` mapping. Also one more question: I know that those "key combinations" are not actually called mappings but I'm not sure how I should call them?

Comment: That's an interesting question, I tend to call them "commands".

Comment: I may be wrong but isn't "command" referring to the ex mode commands like `:ls`, `:substitute`, `new`, etc...?

Comment: `x` is also a "command".

Comment: Indeed I just saw that the doc calls `x`, `dd`, `c`, etc "commands". So you must be right, I guess that `j` or `^J` are also commands.

Comment: @statox the docs call `j`, `h` etc. motions, so that's what I call them.

Comment: @muru damn you're right!